# Insert text in input placeholder from current clicked button's value, jquery/js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**What I am trying achieve**

[image]

With the picture as a reference, I want to get the button pressed to send it's value (in this case the letter 'D') to the yellow area of text inside the input's placeholder.

A working example after clicking the 'D' button would then to show this in the input field "Search for a title or an author within the letter 'D'..."

***Question would then be:*** With jquery/js how can I bring the letter clicked on down to the placeholder of the search input?

**What I've tried**

I tried both jQuery and JavaScript for my attempt to achieve this. But it seems like I am still missing something here.

JS:

```
onclick = function(){
  document.getElementById("#myInput").placeholder = "Search for a title or an author within the letter "+this.dataset.letter;
```

jQuery:

```
$(".letters").click(function(){
    var inputText = $(".letters").val();
    $("#myInput").attr("placeholder", "Search for a title or an author within the letter").val(inputText).focus().blur();
});
```

**What I can provide**

If relevant, my buttons are created from a dataset with jQuery, like this.

```
var letters = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"];

    for (var i in letters){
        $("#letterlinks").append('<button class="table-sort letters" id="#letters" href="%">' + letters[i]);
        $(".table-sort.letters").on('click', function(){
            $(".table-sort.letters.selected").removeClass('selected');
            $(this).addClass('selected');
        });
    }
```

html:

```
<div class="table-search">
     <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="searchInput()" placeholder=""><span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span></input>
</div>
```

If you need any additional information, I'll be quick to provide it for you.
Thank you for your time in advance!

Comment: I think you need to post the relevant markup, too. I don't want to assume what your DOM structure looks like.

Comment: Please post code as a [mcve] by using the button with brackets `<>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the event to get the object of the clicked button.

```
$(".table-sort.letters").on('click', function(event) {
    $(".table-sort.letters.selected").removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');

    $("#myInput").attr("placeholder", "Search for a title or an author within the letter " + event.target.innerText);
});
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, much appreciated!